# Azure PowerShell - Extracting Azure SQL Server information

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I have a requiement to list the following information for all the SQL Servers in our tenancy.

SQL Servers:
Type, Resource Name, Resource Group Name, Location, OS, SKU Name, SQLVM-AHUB, SQLVM-SKU, SQLVM-Offer, vCPUs, SKU, Publisher etc

I have tried Get-AzSqlServer, but that doesn't provide us information other than the ServerName and Tags.

Is there any other command I can try to get the values mentioned above

I tried running Get-AzSqlServer, Get-AzSqlVM, Get-AzSqlDatabaseExpanded, but none of the command would get the information required.

Comment: There isn't any single command that gives you all of that information; You'll need to run separate ARM queries/operations and gather the information yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command below to get details of all instances of SQL Server in the subscription:

```
Get-AzResourceGroup | Get-AzSqlServer
```

You will be able to get the following details of SQL servers in the subscription:

```
ResourceGroupName             : <resourceGroupName>
ServerName                    : <serverName>
Location                      : centralus
SqlAdministratorLogin         : <login>
SqlAdministratorPassword      :
ServerVersion                 : 12.0
Tags                          : {[CreatedBy, kachanum], [CreatedDate, 2/10/2021 5:36:43 AM], [OwningTeam, Databases],
                                [Reason, Repro]}
Identity                      : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models.ResourceIdentity
FullyQualifiedDomainName      : <serverName>.database.windows.net
ResourceId                    : /subscriptions/<subscriptionId>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/
                                providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/<serverName>
MinimalTlsVersion             : None
PublicNetworkAccess           : Enabled
RestrictOutboundNetworkAccess : Disabled
Administrators                : Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Models.ServerExternalAdministrator
PrimaryUserAssignedIdentityId :
KeyId                         :
FederatedClientId             :
```

[image]

For more information, you can refer to this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/get-azsqlserver?view=azps-11.3.0&tryIt=true#example-3-get-all-instances-of-sql-server-in-the-subscription).